# Google Analytics - Custom Report: For every page, how can I find the percentage of that page's visitors that ended up on a certain other page?

Tags: google-analytics

I realize this would be a perfect time to use a goal, but since goals don't work retroactively, I'm trying to find another way to figure this out for past data.

I could add a secondary dimension to see the 'previous page path', but the resulting table isn't what I want. What I'd really like is for the specified page to show up in a column in the screenshot below...

[image: google analytics custom report]

But that doesn't seem to be possible. Is there a way?

Update: Will this show me, for every page, which users ended up on a page containing 'please' within the session?

[image: Advanced Segment Sequence]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Sequences" in Advanced **Segments** and set include session with page A followed (immediately or not) page B.

Comment: Thanks, Michele! I've added a 2nd image up above. I don't want to do it manually for every page, so will that image give me what I need?

Comment: In this case you find sessions that visited those pages, I suggest you another approach using a custom report by setting flat table and dimensions: previous page path and page; metrics: pageviews; filter: page contains '/please'. The result is like 'Navigation summary'. Then don't consider the (entrance).

Comment: That's pretty good, too. Both that approach and the one you inspired in my 2nd screenshot up above give slightly different, useful info. Thanks again!